# Qt: cannot find DLLs even if I specify their location

Tags: qt, dll, linker, linker-errors

I cannot understand why this Qt pro file does not work:

```
QT += core
QT += gui

TARGET = PrjName
CONFIG += qt
CONFIG += console

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt/4.8.4/include/Qt
QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:/Qt/4.8.4/bin
LIBS += -lQtCore4
LIBS += -lQtGui4

SOURCES += ...

HEADERS += ...
```

These are the linker errors:

```
error: cannot find -lQtGui
error: cannot find -lQtCore
```

The `C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin` directory exists, and the DLLs are there.

Thank you.

Platform:  Windows 7, MinGW, Qt 4.8.4, QtCreator 2.8.0

Comment: You don't need to specify -lQtCore4 libraries, it's done automagically with "QT += core gui".  Remove the those two lines with -lQtCore4 and -lQtGui4 and carry on.  Read more about it in the [QtDocumentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-qt-libraries).

Comment: Also the INCLUDEPATH and QMAKE_LIBDIR lines are not necessary.

Comment: @Huytard: you are right, removing those lines it behaves just like before. However the errors are still there.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: the same applies to your suggestion; same behaviour.

Comment: Did you download the wrong Qt package? If you install the MSVC package but then try to build with GCC (mingw), or vice versa, then this happens.

Comment: @NikosC.: I forgot to mention it, but I am working with MinGW.

Comment: Do you use the mingw version that comes with Qt? Or do you use your own? If it's your own, then this might explain it due to version differences in the compiler.

Comment: @NikosC.: I noticed that in my QtCreator/Qt4 directory there is no MinGW executable. The one used is in C:\MinGW\bin, version 4.6.2. On the other hand, in the Qt5 directory it is present (but I am not using Qt5, yet). Could it depend from the way I installed Qt4/QtCreator?